# How can I run selenium (with python) on an open firefox window? (if not, on a Chrome window)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have this python program made with selenium that automates a search on a firefox page, with a login and everything.
The thing is, after the search is done, the program stops executing (the page is still open. I want it that way) but I want to somehow implement a function that when -given certain argument- it searchs for something different on that open firefox page.
I don't know if I explained myself, but this is very important to me.

If you know how to do this but with Chrome I don't mind. I only need it to work regardless of the browser.

I'm not that pro at this, so please be patient with me. I'm very grateful for all the help you could provide me.

Thanks!!

Comment: I could not understand your question fully.. `I want to somehow implement a function that when -given certain argument- it searchs for something different on that open firefox page` I mean what do you mean by args ?

Comment: Lets say you pass the arg continue_search = 0, so it does the login and everything.
Then, with the firefox page open, you re run the program with continue_search = 1, now it goes to a different place in the function and skips the login part just to search

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Interactive_mode:

> Python has two basic modes: script and interactive. The normal mode is
> the mode where the scripted and finished . py files are run in the
> Python interpreter. Interactive mode is a command line shell which
> gives immediate feedback for each statement, while running previously
> fed statements in active memory.

So basically you need to run your code in **interactive mode**. It depends on your IDE: If you use **PyCharm** Right-click on the page that you're writing your code and find *Run File in Python Console* and continue coding in the new window opened by PyCharm. You can also use **Jupyter** which is a great tool for interactive mode. For other IDEs, try to find any menu that is related to interactive mode or window.